# Get a SelectedItems's attribute and pass it to a new page in WP8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, observablecollection

What I'm trying to do is: when a user clicks an item in a listbox, I want to get the item's ID number, which is an attribute. I then want to pass this ID to another page which will display the relevant data.

This is the code I have to attempt to do this:

```
private void lstCats_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        Pets selectedAnimal = lstCats.SelectedItem as Pets;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewPet.xaml?msg=" + selectedAnimal.ID, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

and then on the second page, where I want to display the data, I have the following:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

        string msg = "";

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("msg", out msg))
        {
            id = Convert.ToInt16(msg);

            DisplayDetails();
            DisplayImage();
        }
    }
```

From what I can tell the problem lies on the first page, as the second page is working fine when linked to other pages, where I'm not using listboxes, etc.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: The code I'm using to populate the listboxes:

```
private void DisplayCats()
    {
        foreach (Pets temp in thisApp.pets)
        {
            if (temp.Category.Contains("Cat"))
            {
                Animal animal = new Animal() { Details = temp.Name + "\n" + temp.Category + " / " + temp.Subcategory + "\n€" + temp.Price.ToString(), ImageURI = temp.Image };
                lstCats.Items.Add(animal);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code you used to bind/populate your `dropdownlist`?

Comment: added it to the original question, cheers

Comment: You're binding items to dropdown as `Animal`, but trying to cast them back to `Pet` later. That can't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue is with this line:

```
Pets selectedAnimal = lstCats.SelectedItem as Pets;
```

The problem, here, is that your `ListBox` control has items that have `Animal`s as their `SelectedItem`s. What you will want to do is instead bind the `ListBox` with pets, instead of items:

```
private void DisplayCats()
{
    foreach (Pets temp in thisApp.pets)
    {
        if (temp.Category.Contains("Cat"))
        {
            lstCats.Items.Add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

Assuming you want to bind with `Animal` objects, you can do the following:

```
private void DisplayCats()
{
    foreach (Pets temp in thisApp.pets)
    {
        if (temp.Category.Contains("Cat"))
        {
            //note that I added the ID property --v
            Animal animal = new Animal() { ID = temp.ID, Details = temp.Name + "\n" + temp.Category + " / " + temp.Subcategory + "\n€" + temp.Price.ToString(), ImageURI = temp.Image };
            lstCats.Items.Add(animal);
        }
    }
}
```

Then your event handler should look like:

```
private void lstCats_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Animal selectedAnimal = lstCats.SelectedItem as Animal;
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ViewPet.xaml?msg=" + selectedAnimal.ID, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry about the confusion, before. I just misread the post. This answer has been updated to fit your solution. If you just change your `DisplayCats` method to this one, it should work.

Comment: thanks. but doing this doesn't display anything though, and I'm not sure how it would?

Comment: What does your front-end do to determine what properties of the `Animal`/`Pet` objects to display in the `ListBox`? Whatever it does, update it to find the corresponding properties on the `Pets` class.

Comment: Unless the code you posted for creating your `Animal` objects is incomplete, the `Animal` objects' `ID`s should be null or whatever their default values are. I will update my solution to account for this, in case you just forgot to add that in.